# PHPSESSID changes on every page reload in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I have the trouble with session id in IE (our project supports 9+).  Everytime I reload the page, the session id changes. In other browsers everything is ok.
session_start() calls in index.php (it is the single entry point for all requests) and there no error messages on server-size or client-side. The PHPSESSID cookie creates.

Apache 2.2
PHP 5.4.25

There are php.ini configurations for sessions:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = On
session.bug_compat_warn = On
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Maybe someone faced with the same problem, because I googled all day and didn't find any solution.

Comment: Do you have cookies turned off in internet security settings in control panel

Comment: I've come across this several times recently. The answer in all of my cases has been that the subdomain or domain contains an '_' character - IE seems to throw up because of this. I think the cookie was still showing up, but it was being recreated each time. Please let me know if this was the cause and I will add it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: Problem caused by '_' character in domain name. Thanks for your assistance, @ClarkeyBoy.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've added it as an answer below. I'm actually experiencing the same symptoms now, which is how I came across this, but it's not the same cause :(. Found that some code in a file which, as far as I can tell, is not even being included is still being executed. Any debug statements I add to the file are not even output - but other code executes unless it is commented out. Really weird. Anyway I'm on higher priority things now so that issue can wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this several times recently. The answer in all of my cases has been that the subdomain or domain contains an '_' character - IE seems to throw up because of this. I think the cookie was still showing up, but it was being recreated each time.